# csf stop emails related to Process Tracking

Tags: csf

I have enabled LSF with CSF since I would like to receive some informations but I am being bombed by the CSF with similar emails:

```
Subject: lfd on [Hostname]: Excessive resource usage: www-data

Time: Sun Jan 19 21:29:17 2014 +0100
Account: www-data
Resource: Virtual Memory Size
Exceeded: 279 > 200 (MB)
Executable: /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-itk/apache2
Command Line: /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
PID: 22991 (Parent PID:12217)
Killed: No
```

I have disabled the Process Tracking section in csf.conf and still receiving these logs.

```
# Set the value to 0 to disable this feature
PT_LIMIT = "0"

# How frequently processes are checked in seconds
PT_INTERVAL = "3600"
```

I have checked many times csf.conf but cannot find the right place to stop these logs. Restarting csf does not help... Anyone knows if this is a peculiar configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add cmd:/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
to csf.pignore file and restart CSF and LFD (you might need to kill the lfd process)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old thread but did you try running **csf -r** to reload the config? OR if you want to permanently stop emails you can change **LF_PERMBLOCK_ALERT** from **1** to **0**

Answer (score -1):

sometimes restart the csf not solving your issue.
I have try change the email like admin@example.com to report@example.com. but alert always sending to admin@example.com

just restart your server and then will be fix soon